# Using Apache Spark, how to count the occurrences of each pair in a Scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I need to count the occurrences of each pair that is present in a Scala `Array`, and the later is distributed. So :

1. I must count the occurrences of each pair that is present on the `RDD`s of my cluster's nodes (i.e. : "on each part of the distributed `Array`"). It means I will have x results^1, with x : the number of my cluster's nodes.
2. Then, the driver must add up the results, to know the distributed `Array`'s number of occurrences of each pair.

^1 : please, note that one result is a cluster's node count of each pair of its own part of the distributed `Array`. I think a `HashMap` would be fine to use there. By the way, a `HashMap` will be used by the driver too. The driver will have to sum up each case of its `HashMap` with the corresponding case of the `HashMap`s that it receives from the cluster nodes.

ILLUSRATION :
[image]

Comment: care to share an example dataset and expected output?

Comment: Of course ! I just added a diagram to illustrate my words. The input and output datasets are given.

Comment: can you not paste attach images of your data but paste code and data in a reproducible format?

Comment: Well, the code is very basic : `spark_context.parallelize(my_input_dataset_Array).` and I don't know what to put after the final point. I know what I want to do (cf. my image), but not how to use Spark to do it.

Comment: But I know Spark's working and some of the submechanisms* I just don't know how to realise what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need the "**reduceByKeyLocally**" :

```
    val result: collection.Map[(String, String), Int] = context
      .parallelize(Seq(("BLUE", "RED"), ("RED", "GREEN"), ("YELLOW", "ORANGE")))
      .map(colorPair => (colorPair, 1))
      .reduceByKeyLocally(_ + _)
```

reduceByKeyLocally map locally first, merge locally (using foreachPartition) and call the action of reduce

Comment: Does `.map(colorPair => (colorPair, 1))` increments the number of occurrences, or just sets it at 1 ? If a given node has 2 `("BLUE", "RED")`, then the number of occurrences must be 2 in the `HashMap` of this node. Thus, the "1" of your instruction seems to be odd no ?

Comment: It is a classical "WORD COUNT" scenario - it creates JHashMap[K, V] for each of the elements and merges them so it finally becomes what you wanted - (("BLUE", "RED"),n)

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question but you are correct, the ".map" part just sets it to 1 for each pair

Comment: According to the documentation, `reduceByKeyLocally/reduceByKeyToDriver` is a simple `reduceByKey` that returns a `Map` to the driver (that's the only difference). So, does it do an implicit `collect` ?

Comment: *mapPartition - does what it says it does - applies map on each partition.
                         this is usually what you need for dealing with local 
                         resources
*reduce - actually runs a job of "reducePartition" which uses reduceLeft on each partition and defines a handler for the results that merges all the results

*reduceByKey - is not an action and in order to accomplish the merged results on the cluster it needs to shuffle - and the result of it is actually a ShuffledRDD.

hope this helps